# Term of "short leg of more than one Pythagorean triangle" sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, pythagorean-triples

Is there any way to represent in a closed form (or a simple algo) the $n$-th term of the sequence:

```
9, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 60, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 72, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 98, 99, 100, 102, 104, 105, 108, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, ...
```

[A009188 Short leg of more than one Pythagorean triangle](https://oeis.org/A009188)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the omitted values are $p,2p$ for all primes $p$ (and $2^3$). For these values there aren't many options to get a triple $(2uv,u^2-v^2,u^2+v^2)$. For $n=r\cdot s; r,s\geq 3$ I would assume that there are at least two triples with $n$ as a short leg. But this requires a proof.

Comment: Very helpful @TomTom314. I think you are right about your conjecture.

Comment: At a second glance the OEIS page states the same criterion, cmp. Mathematica & Maple entries.